# How to navigate between pages in Xamarin.Forms for F#

Tags: f#, xamarin.forms

I'm building a Xamarin.Forms app in F#.  So far it's pretty great, but I can't figure out how to navigate between pages.  In C#, I normally do something like this:

```
var tapRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapRecognizer .Tapped += async (s, e) =>
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyNewPage());
```

`Navigation.PushAsync` does not seem to be available in F#.  Is there an alternative, or is navigation tucked away in a namespace other than `Xamarin.Forms`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is pretty simple:

```
this.Navigation.PushAsync(MyNewPage())
```

I was missing the explicit `this` call.  Sheer brilliance.

Comment: I am trying the same thing but I am getting this:

Error FS0039: The value, namespace, type or module 'this' is not defined. Maybe you want one of the following: ThisAssembly (FS0039)